# Is there a way to ask time.After() for an infinite amount of time?

Tags: go, time

Is there a way to ask `time.After()` for an infinite amount of time?

Motivation:  I have a service that a caller can request a message from, with an optional timeout.  The obvious way to do this would be:

```
func service(timeout *time.Duration) SomeType {
    var timeout_value time.Duration
    if timeout != nil {
        timeout_value = *timeout
    } else {
        timeout_value = time.Forever /* or something */
    }

    select {
    case value <- some_channel:
        return value
    case <- time.After(timeout_value):
        return nil
    }
}
```

Except I don't know if there's a way to say `time.Forever`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "forever" duration, but there is max duration:

```
const maxDuration time.Duration = 1<<63 - 1
```

`maxDuration` is about 292 years. It should be enough for the lifetime of a single app. But instead I propose the below solution which doesn't use it:

Note that if "forever" is the intended max wait time, it's simpler and more efficient to omit `time.After()` and use a simple receive:

```
func service(timeout *time.Duration) SomeType {
    if timeout == nil {
        return <-some_channel
    }

    select {
    case value := <-some_channel:
        return value
    case <-time.After(*timeout):
        return nil
    }
}
```

You indicated that your actual code is much more complex and contains more cases.

In that case, I'd move the timeout channel creation outside of the `select` statement, and initialize accordingly. When `timeout` is `nil`, just leave the channel `nil` (its zero value), which will never deliver any value, so receiving from a `nil` channel literally takes "forever":

```
func service(timeout *time.Duration) SomeType {
    var timeoutCh <-chan time.Time
    if timeout != nil {
        timeoutCh = time.After(*timeout)
    }

    select {
    case value := <-some_channel:
        return value
    case <-timeoutCh:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I predict in the year 2313 some museum curator will be cursing you when their only display unit of some app stops working.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, I fear that, and I'm sure he'll come back here and downvote this answer even though my proposed solution doesn't even use `maxDuration` :)

Comment: Why not `1<<64 - 1`?

Comment: @super: Because it's an int64, not a uint64.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because I think my app might run for 292 years :-)  But I don't like the proposed solution; in practice, the body of the `select` is long and complex and reiterating it is painful.  There are in fact six `case`s, each with quite a lengthy body.  It might be time to think about refactoring this, but that's how it is at present.

Comment: @Tom All right then, see my edited answer. In short: just move the timeout channel creation outside of `select`, and let it remain `nil` if you want to wait forever. Receiving from a `nil` channel blocks forever.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the duration you could accept a [`context.Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) in your function, which I think is quite idiomatic in Go code.

Then the caller can call the function with a [`Context.Background`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Background) or with a [`Context.WithTimeout`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout) as needed. The `service` function selects on the context's `Done()`, which in case of the background context never ends (the chan is effectively nil).

> Done may return nil if this context can never be canceled. [...] Done is provided for use in select statements

```
func callerNoTimeout() {
    foo := service(context.Background())
}

func callerTimeout() {
    foo := service(context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeOut))
}

func service(ctx context.Context) SomeType {
    select {
        case value <-some_channel:
            return value
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it's common practice to use a `time.Duration` of `0` (or negative) to indicate no timeout - so it's not necessary to pass a pointer.

Secondly, just check for this zero-value when enforcing a timeout or not:

```
func service(timeout time.Duration) SomeType {
    
    if timeout <= 0 {
        return <- some_channel

    }

    select {
        case value <- some_channel:
            return value
        case <- time.After(timeout):
            return nil
    }
}
```